# TabBarController top bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I added a tabBarCotroller to my app. WhenI run the app in simulator/phone a big bar appears on top of each page. This bar does not appear in the storyboard. How can I remove it? I want the app to extend all the way to the top[image]

Comment: is your view controller embeded in a navigation controller?

Comment: No it is not embedded in navigation controller

Comment: edited my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide for all view controllers in the app that share the same `UINavigationController` use this

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

If you are not using a `UINavigationController` then try this:

Select your ViewController

[image]

and then select

[image]